# How can I change the default macro paths in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The macro likes $(Configuration) is a relative directory in the Solution
I want to change it to be a absolute path.

I don't want to add a macro or enviroment variable, I just want to change default macro.

Answer (score -1):

1. From project properties>Linker>Additional Library directory>Macros
   Which will allow you to change macro.
2. use batch file.

Comment: No, I wasn't want to Additional Library directory for use Macros. I just want to change the value of the  default macro.